# Problem with reactive function, trying to change the type of the column of a dataset that is being imported (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

It is my first time uploading anything or asking anything.
I am new to R Shiny. I need to build a Shiny website where I will upload a time-series CSV file and do some simple graphing.
For the X variable, I want the Date column to be used.
The Date column is in character, so I tried to change it to DateTime type in R.
At the same time, I wanted to select the range of the data from the Date column and use that for plotting.
I tried to subset the dataset.
I am getting an error that says "getdate" cannot be found. "getdata" is a reactive function.

```
   library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- (fixedPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Covid-19 Data of MA"),
  titlePanel("File Input"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("csvfile","Upload the file", multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values","text/plain",".csv"),
                width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
                placeholder = "No file selected"),
      helpText("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
      tags$hr(),
      h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "String As Factors", value = FALSE),
      br(),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
      width = 3
    ),
    mainPanel(width = 9,
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("About File", tableOutput("filedf")),
        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),
        tabPanel("Interactive Graph",
                 fluidRow(
                   selectInput(inputId = "column_name",
                               label = "Choose a X Variable:",
                               choices=NULL,
                               selected=NULL,
                               multiple = FALSE,
                               width="450px"),
                   dateRangeInput("date-range-input",label="Select Date Range for the Y Variable",
                                  start = min(getdata()$Date),
                                  end = max(getdata()$Date),
                                  min = min(getdata()$Date),
                                  max = max(getdata()$Date),
                                  format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                                  separator = "-"
                                  )
                 ),
                 plotOutput("graph"))),
      tableOutput("modified_dset"),
      uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

# ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

server <- (function(session, input, output){

  getdata <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  })

#  format="%Y-%m-%d"
  modified_dset <- eventReactive(input$date-range-input, {
    getdata()[, input$date-range-input] <- lubridate::date_decimal(getdata()[,input$date-range-input])
  })

  # Update SelectInput Dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "column_name", label="Choose a X Variable:", choices = names(getdata()),selected=NULL)
  })

  # Data file info
  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(modified_dset())){return ()}
    input$csvfile
  })

  # Interactive Graph
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(modified_dset())){return ()}
    dataset <- modified_dset()
    subset_data = subset(dataset, dataset$Date>=input$date-range-input[1] & dataset$Date<=input$date-range-input[2])
    ggplot(data = subset_data, aes_string(x = Date, y = input$column_name, group = 1))+
      geom_line(col = "blue", lwd =1)+labs(x = "Date", y = input$column_name)
  })

  # Table of the Dataset
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(modified_dset())){return ()}
    getdata()
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to call a reactive inside your `ui`, which should essentially be **static**. All reactives must stay within `server`. Your error lies in using

```
dateRangeInput("date-range-input",label="Select Date Range for the Y Variable",
                                  start = min(getdata()$Date),
                                  end = max(getdata()$Date),
                                  min = min(getdata()$Date),
                                  max = max(getdata()$Date),
                                  format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                                  separator = "-"
                                  )
```

within `ui`. The solution is to add this to `server`

```
output$myDateInput <- renderUI({
   dateRangeInput("date-range-input", label="Select Date Range for the Y Variable",
                                  start = min(getdata()$Date),
                                  end = max(getdata()$Date),
                                  min = min(getdata()$Date),
                                  max = max(getdata()$Date),
                                  format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                                  separator = "-"
                                  )
)}
```

Then remove that dateRangeInput from your `ui` code and replace it with:

```
uiOutput("myDateInput")
```

Comment: Note: you've done this properly for your selectInput (although I'd recommend the `renderUI` route over `observe` + `updateSelectInput`). Also, you're going to get an error from `input$date-range-input` because R will interpret the dash as subtraction -- you can either use `input[["date-range-input"]]` or rename your inputId. Finally, I'd recommend `renderDataTable` from the `DT` package over `renderTable`, as it already has error-checking for empty tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sample csv file using this code

```
tibble(Date = seq(Sys.Date()-59, Sys.Date(),1), col1 = 1:60, col2 = 61:120) %>% 
            mutate(Date = Date %>% as.character()) %>% 
            write_csv("date.csv")
```

There are a few more issues in your shiny code.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- (fixedPage(
    headerPanel(title = "Covid-19 Data of MA"),
    titlePanel("File Input"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("csvfile","Upload the file", multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values","text/plain",".csv"),
                      width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
                      placeholder = "No file selected"),
            helpText("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
            tags$hr(),
            h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
            checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = T), # I made it True so that the file header will be selected by default
            checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "String As Factors", value = FALSE),
            br(),
            radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
            width = 3
        ),
        mainPanel(width = 9,
                  tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("About File", tableOutput("filedf")),
                      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),
                      tabPanel("Interactive Graph",
                               fluidRow(
                                   selectInput(inputId = "column_name",
                                               label = "Choose a X Variable:",
                                               choices=NULL,
                                               selected=NULL,
                                               multiple = FALSE,
                                               width="450px"),
                                   dateRangeInput("date_range_input",label="Select Date Range for the Y Variable",
                                                  start = Sys.Date()-60, #I'm giving a default values with sys.Date which we will update once the file is uploaded using updateDateRangeInput from the server side
                                                  end = Sys.Date(), # you can add further parameters like min and max if you wish
                                   )
                               ),
                               plotOutput("graph"))),
                  #tableOutput("modified_dset"), I don't see any output for this
                  uiOutput("tb")
        )
    )
))
```

You're working with the assumption that the date column will have the column name as 'Date' so I went with the same assumption. Since UI have no idea what date range you file contains we have to update it from server-side using updateDateRangeInput after reading the file. You can use renderUI instead.

Since your date column is in character I changed it to Date format in the first reactive itself. This is to simplify, you can choose to do it in separate reactive as well but you need the date column in Date format for selection in updateDateRangeInput.

In `getdata` reactive `input$csvfile` should be your id instead of `input$file`

```
server <- (function(session, input, output){
    
    getdata <- reactive({
        file1 <- input$csvfile
        if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
        read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors) %>% 
            mutate(Date = Date %>% lubridate::as_date())
        
    })
    
    observe({
        data11 <<- getdata()
    })
    
    
    
    observe({
      
        
        updateDateRangeInput(session, inputId = "date_range_input", label="Select Date Range for the Y Variable",
                             start = min(getdata()$Date),
                             end = max(getdata()$Date),
        )
        
    })
    

   

    # Update SelectInput Dynamically
    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, "column_name", label="Choose a X Variable:", choices = names(getdata()),selected=NULL)
    })

    # Data file info
    output$filedf <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(getdata())){return ()}
        getdata()
    })

    # Interactive Graph
    output$graph <- renderPlot({
        if(is.null(getdata())){return ()}
        dataset <- getdata()
        subset_data = subset(dataset, dataset$Date>=input$date_range_input[1] & dataset$Date<=input$date_range_input[2])
        ggplot(data = subset_data, aes(x = Date, y = input$column_name, group = 1))+
            geom_line(col = "blue", lwd =1)+labs(x = "Date", y = input$column_name)
    })

    # Table of the Dataset
    output$table <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(getdata())){return ()}
        getdata()
    })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```